# opencv object detection only scale not rotation

Tags: opencv, scale, shapes, object-detection

SIFT and SURF is scale and rotation invariant. I want to detect object that is only scale invariant. Are there any function or sample code / function in openCV that can do this. I do not want rotation invariant only scale invariant.

Answer (score 1):

[BRIEF](http://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/d7d/tutorial_py_brief.html#gsc.tab=0) is not designed to be rotation invariant.

Citing from [original paper](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/rg/papers/CalonderLSF10.pdf):

> **Orientation Sensitivity:** BRIEF is not designed to be rotationally invariant.
>   Nevertheless [...] it tolerates small amounts of rotation.

Comment: There is a statement at the end of the paper that states.. "In future work, we will incorporate orientation and scale invariance into BRIEF so that it can compete with SURF and SIFT in a wider set of situations. " Is it scale invariant ?

Comment: It should be, you need to check on a few images. Why do you need a "non rotation invariant" descriptor? Can't you just use sift (or similar) and discard rotated matches?